# In Redis pubsub, is it possible to pass an object to the PUBLISH command?

Tags: redis

I have an application which inserts record to a postgresql table and after the insert, I want to send a PUBLISH command to redis. Is it possible to pass an object of that record to redis' PUBLISH command so the subscriber on the other end will receive the object too?

Comment: You can additionally use Hash - it is the closest to an object. And can be queried based on fields. This cannot be done by encoding/decoding JSON.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Redis has no meaning of "objects", all redis gets are bytes, specifically strings!
So when you want to publish an object you have to serialize it some way and deserialize it on the subscriber.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but because redis stores strings rather than objects, you'll need to serialize/unserialize objects as part of the PUBLISH process. JSON is an ideal format for this.

Comment: I am getting hardtime publishing a json object.. all i am getting at other end is integers... :/ Can you help me with a sample command to publish JSON object?

Answer (score 4):

This question has been asked a long time ago, however, if anyone gets here, this worked for me using the nodejs redis library.

`npm i redis`

The easiest way if you are using node.js is to simply publish like this:

```js
const data = {
   name: 'John Doe',
   age: 0
};

publisher.publish('<channel_name>', JSON.stringify(data));
```

The client subscriber can then read using the following code:

```js
subscriber.on('message', (channel, message) => {
   const data = JSON.parse(message);
   console.log(data);
   // your code goes here to do whatever you want with the data
});

subscriber.subscribe('<channel_name>');
```

Result:

```js
{name: 'John Doe', age: 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

**For python developers**. Serialize python dict using json.dumps().

**Publisher**

```
import json 

payload_dict = {
 'key1':'value1',
 'key2':'value2'
}

data = json.dumps(payload_dict)
publisher.publish('channel', data)
```

**Subscriber**

```
 data = subscriber.get('data').decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: how do you get the publisher and subscriber?!