# Sending an image with an ID across processes in Python, Windows

Tags: python, shared-memory

I have a project with multiple Python processes on the same computer.

Python process A is the central node, and it receives images and data from sensors.

Python process A sends images to process B for image processing/feature detection, and process B sends back some information to process A. The system is much more complex than this which is why it's separated in the first place.

One idea that I want to implement is to tag the images with an integer, let's say `x`. This way, process B can say "Hi process A, this is the data for image `x`".

**The problem is, how can I send both images and this integer elegantly and rapidly across processes?**

Ideas:

- Use MQTT or ZeroMQ to communicate. Turn image into string, put it in a dict with the id, send it. I think these will be slow because we are serializing lots of images and sending lots of data over these chunky protocols.
- Use [Shared memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) to share the image. I have prototyped this, it is very fast to send images, but encoding the integer is not elegant. I would maybe encode the integer into the RGB value of a few pixels in the corner, but this feels janky.
- Pickling might be better than string serialization since its bytes vs strings and so much faster? The [multiprocessing pipes and queues](https://superfastpython.com/multiprocessing-pipe-in-python/#How_to_Use_the_Pipe) seem like they are for this, but the sender and receiver seem to need to start in the same Python thread.
- Find a unique hash for each image in every process. I'm leaning towards this option right now, it's very easy to understand but probably not the fastest.

I recognize this is an architecture question and those are frowned upon, but I feel like there has to be a more elegant solution and I think this is an interesting design problem to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I find **Redis** great for this type of thing. Imagine it as a blazing fast, *"in-memory"* datastructure server that can serve atomic integers, strings, images, lists, queues, sets, sorted sets, JSON, streams, PUB/SUB ...  [here](https://redis.io/commands/) are the commands to create/read objects.

It has bindings for C, C++, Python, Ruby, PHP and `bash` commandline so you can inject and check test data easily just from the shell.

And it's entirely distributed across networks.

And it handles binary data (no need for serialisation) and keys and values up to 512MB.

So you can create a **Redis** object containing a JPEG/PNG/TIFF or raw image of binary data ([SET](https://redis.io/commands/set/)), then push ([LPUSH](https://redis.io/commands/lpush/)) a JSON containing the object name and `id` onto a queue for processing.

Run as many processing nodes as you need doing `pops` off the queue ([BRPOP](https://redis.io/commands/brpop/)), and scale by adding more.

Have another `results` queue where workers put another JSON with their answers and corresponding `id`.

You can also specify a *"Time-To-Live"* so that datastructures are automagically deleted after a given time.

You can also create persistance across reboots, if you want to.

You can also add redundancy, if you want to cluster it.

I have done many examples, try searching for my username and `Redis` and `image`. Hopefully, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2836621%20image%20redis) will work.

Comment: This looks very promising. I will look into it. Does it being distributed across networks mean that, if computer A is connected to computer B as an access point, they could be talking to the same Redis database?

Comment: It hasn't actually got anything to do with access points or wifi, it is standard TCP/IP like web browsers, Email. As long as all machines involved can reach the machine running Redis somehow by some route, they can exchange data. One  machine could be cabled to the Internet via your home router, another could be using your cell-phone as a wifi hotspot - as long as they can see/ping each other, or a third machine somewhere else where Redis is running, it can work.

Comment: This seems to disagree with what you said regarding bytes vs serialization: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5192528/11741232
Could you help me understand how to avoid turning my images to json strings?

Comment: Or rather, I was really hoping to make the object -> object in another python process faster than json serialization, but it seems like its still necessary? I might just have unjustified perception of how slow json serialization is.

Comment: As regards the second option in your question, there's nothing stopping you putting the megabyte or two of bulk image data in a shared memory buffer, but sending the id/tag plys byte offset into the buffer via a MQTT/zeromq. That way you get the speed of shared memory for the bulky data and the low bandwidth synchronisation/control/metadata path via MQTT/zeromq.